# JQuery show and hide multiple textboxes

Tags: jquery

I have two checkboxes that show a textbox when checked. The code below works, although I do not think it is very efficient. I wonder if there is an easy way to combine the 'checked'-code for the checkboxes, in case you have more than two. Notice I did not use the `.toggle` method. The first reason is because it is not clear if a checkbox is initially checked or not. Secondly, I read the `.toggle` method is deprecated. But maybe others think I should use it anyway in this case.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //initial check
    show_hide();    

    $(".checkbox1").change(function() {
        show_hide();        
    });
    $(".checkbox2").change(function() {
        show_hide();            
    });

    function show_hide(){
        if($(".checkbox1").prop('checked') == true) {
            $("#textbox1").show();
        } else {
            $("#textbox1").hide();
        }   
        if($(".checkbox2").prop('checked') == true) {
            $("#textbox2").show();
        } else {
            $("#textbox2").hide();
        }   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be more efficient code example than yours. Using Same `class` with Unique `ID`.

```js
$('.check_box').change(function(){
    if($('.check_box:checked').length==0){
        $('.checkbox').show();
    }else{
        $('.checkbox').hide();
        $('.check_box:checked').each(function(){
            $('#'+$(this).attr('data-ptag')).show();
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="sb1" class="checkbox">Checkbox One</p>
<p id="sb2" class="checkbox">Checkbox Two</p>

   <input name="chk1" class="check_box" type="checkbox" data-ptag="sb1" id="chk1" value="">Check Box1
   <input name="chk2" class="check_box" type="checkbox" data-ptag="sb2" id="chk2" value="">Check Box2
```

Comment: This is the kind of solution I was looking for, but in your example there is no initial 'checked'-check. And it shows the two paragraphs when the two checkboxes are unchecked.